# Angular ng-if and changing Twitter Bootstrap col-sm

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

OK, here is the code:
    
       
          left block
       
       
          right block

It shows left block on the left part of screen and right block on the right of screen, if a screen is small or wider. And it shows right block under the left block for screens that are smaller than small (as two simple dives). That's clear.

I would like to use ng-if="boolValue" for the right block so that when it is hidden, then the left block is in the middle of the screen, not on the left.

What's the best way to do it?

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      left block in the center
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6" ng-if="boolValue">
      when right block is hidden because of falsy boolValue
   </div>
</div>
```

What's the technique to make it done? The best thing that comes to my mind is to use ng-if something like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12" ng-if="!boolValue">
      left block in the center
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6" ng-if="boolValue">
      left block in the center <the same content as above>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6" ng-if="boolValue">
      when right block is hidden because of falsy boolValue
   </div>
</div>
```

but I don't think that's the proper and the best way.

Comment: use ng-class="{{'col-sm-6':boolValue,'col-sm-12':!boolValue}}",  see my code below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
   <div ng-class="{'col-sm-12': !boolValue, 'col-sm-6': boolValue}" ng-if="!boolValue">
      left block in the center
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6" ng-if="boolValue">
      when right block is hidden because of falsy boolValue
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="row">    
   <div ng-class="{'col-sm-6':boolValue,'col-sm-12':!boolValue}">

   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6" ng-if="boolValue">

   </div>
</div>
```